# What is a not-well-founded cotree?

Tags: trees, category-theory, duality

I'm reading the paper "Dual of substitution is Redecoration".
And I'm struggling with understanding the usage of the word "not-well-founded cotrees".

1. what is a cotree compared to a tree ? I suspect it is a tree for which all relations are inverted, but it is just my assumption.
2. what it is to be "well-founded" for a tree, for a cotree.

Probably, to have an insight, it would be helpful to give me examples of a well-founded and of a not-well-founded tree/cotree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "all relations are inverted" (what's the relation of a tree?), but perhaps I can provide some insight.

In [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)), one might write the type of binary trees as such:

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Tree Tree
```

in the terminology of the paper, the type of "incomplete trees" would then be

```
data ITree a = Leaf | Node ITree ITree | Var a
```

allowing for an "incomplete" tree with holes marked by an instance of `Var a`. The paper observes that the type `ITree a` forms a monad, where a `Var a` can be "substituted" with `f a` given a suitable function `f :: a -> ITree b`.

Now our intuition is that the type `Tree` is the type of finite, or **well-founded** binary trees, of which an example is

```
 myTree :: Tree
 myTree = Node (Node Leaf Leaf) (Node Leaf Leaf)
```

However, it is untrue in a language like Haskell that *all* trees are of this form. Indeed, following definition is perfectly acceptable:

```
infTree :: Tree
infTree = Node infTree infTree
```

intuitively, this tree represents the infinite "full" binary tree. So really the type `Tree` may contain either finite binary trees, or trees which may contain infinite paths. **Such trees are called non-well founded trees**.

So, in Haskell, the type `Tree` is *in reality* the type of co-trees, which allows such elements as `infTree`. This may be a bit confusing, since we rarely think about such elements when considering that type.

Hopefully this provides useful intuition.

The main observation of the paper, is that the type of co-trees has a construction dual to that if `ITree`, which one might call `DTree`, defined as

```
 DTree a = DLeaf a | DNode a (DTree a) (DTree a)
```

such that we can define a *comonad structure*:

```
extract :: DTree a -> a
extract (DLeaf a) = a
extract (DNode a _ _) = a

duplicate :: DTree a -> DTree (DTree a)
duplicate (DLeaf a) = DLeaf (DLeaf a)
duplicate (DNode a l r) = DNode (DNode a l r) (duplicate l) (duplicate r)
```

The paper goes on to explain some intuition about this structure and why it should be considered as interesting.

---

Oh by the way, the paper you are reading seems pretty heavy in abstract nonsense, and if you're coming from the CS side of things, you might want to take a look at these blog posts first:

https://bartoszmilewski.com/2013/06/10/understanding-f-algebras/

http://5outh.blogspot.com/2013/01/comonads.html

Comment: "What's the relation in a tree ?" It may be naive, but I was thinking of this relationship: Parent to Children nodes. The assumed inverted/dual structure would have been a graph, with lots of parents/roots and each could have only one child, but this child can have several/numerous parent nodes. The graph is terminated on a unique leaf which would be the final unique child ( dual to the unique root of a normal tree). That was an assumption :-)

Comment: @StephaneRolland I see. In this case however, cotrees have the same "shape" as trees, just potentially infinite paths in them.

Comment: Shouldn't "incomplete trees" be defined by `Node ITree ITree | Var a` (i.e. without the initial `Leaf` in the second code box above?)

Comment: @Luciano No, in this case, "incomplete trees" really means "potentially incomplete trees". In particular, a tree without variables is also an incomplete tree.